# pip install fbprophet

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-buster

Can the facebook time series algorithm called prophet be installed on a rasp pi?

It requires pystan (I think its Cython) and my B+ pi upgraded to Buster fails on the install with `pip`

Im also noticing the RAM requirements maybe not enough for the B+ which I only think has 1 gig of RAM. I was just curious if this could be installed on the pi or not?

> Linux Make sure compilers (gcc, g++, build-essential) and Python
> development tools (python-dev, python3-dev) are installed. In Red Hat
> systems, install the packages gcc64 and gcc64-c++. If you are using a
> VM, be aware that you will need at least 4GB of memory to install
> fbprophet, and at least 2GB of memory to use fbprophet.

Comment: It looks to me like a bug in their setup, making it impossible to build from source. piwheels failed to build to because of this. I've created an issue: https://github.com/piwheels/packages/issues/167 and will take it up with the maintainers.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get the same error when I try to run the pip install on Windows 10 as well. Would you still post an answer if you figure it out?

Comment: Will do. Also you can follow here: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1716